# Single return statement in a method but object cannot be instantiated. No return statement error

Tags: java, return, abstract

We learnt that it's good coding practice in Java to only have a single return statement in a method. However, here is my problem;

I have an abstract superclass, Action. There are subclasses like WalkAction, JumpAction, DoNothingAction etc. There is a method in the Actor's class that returns an action based on the requirements in the if-else if-else loop. How am I supposed to only have 1 return statement if the Action class cannot be instantiated. Right now the method looks something like this;

```
private Action getAction(Actor actor, Distance distance) {
   if (distance < 5) {
       return new JumpAction(actor);
   }
   else if (distance > 5 && distance < 10) {
       return new WalkAction(actor);
   }
   else {
       return new DoNothingAction(actor);
   }
}
```

It's also showing an error that there is no return statement

Comment: "*We learnt that it's good coding practice to only have a single return statement in a method.*" I strongly disagree.

Comment: @melpomene Well, the problem is that it's also showing no return statement error

Comment: Does the error go away if you remove `else {` and `}`?

Comment: "It's also showing an error that there is no return statement"  I am sure its is  not!!

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code to the following single `return` form:

```
private Action getAction(Actor actor, Distance distance) {
   Action action;
   if (distance < 5) {
       action = new JumpAction(actor);
   }
   else if (distance > 5 && distance < 10) {
       action = new WalkAction(actor);
   }
   else {
       action = new DoNothingAction(actor);
   }
   return action;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
private Action getAction(Actor actor, Distance distance) {
   return
       distance < 5                  ? new JumpAction(actor) :
       distance > 5 && distance < 10 ? new WalkAction(actor) :
       new DoNothingAction(actor);
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because Action is an abstract class and can't be instantiated :/

Comment: @llamaro25 My code doesn't try to instantiate `Action`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I found a way to go about it. I first initialise Action action = new DoNothingAction(actor); then I test the conditions. So I'll return action in the end if none of the conditions are fulfilled

Answer (score 0):

Add "return null" out of the "if-else" block.
The compiler doesn't know your runtime info, it's possible that the whole "if-else" block 
 is not matched at all then you end up with "no return statement" error.